# Setting two argument in one data

Tags: python

First, this is my code:

```
import re

clientaddress = ('192.168.10.111', 43567)
x = re.search("\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\$", clientaddress)
print (x)
if x:
  print("YES! We have a match!")
else:
  print("No match")
```

Here is the problem. the **'ClientAddress'** is imported from another server and its format is like this:
('IP', port)
So we have an (str, int).
the error is :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

After that, if I use this code:

```
import re


clientaddress = str('192.168.31.111', 43567)
clientaddress = ('192.168.31.111', 43567)
x = re.search("\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\$", clientaddress)
print (x)
if x:
  print("YES! We have a match!")
else:
  print("No match")
```

The error that appeared is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: str() argument 2 must be str, not int
```

Comment: seperate match 'IP' and port  will be easiest way.

Comment: It can't be separated, it should be this way.

Comment: I mean you can declare new var `ip = clientaddress[0]` , then use `re` to match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clientAddress` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) containing a string as the first element.

so index the tuple first and do the checking then. (`clientaddress[0]`)

```
clientaddress = ('192.168.10.111', 43567)
x = re.search("\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+$", clientaddress[0])
print(x)
```

Comment: @RezaAzimi I think you didn't remove `str` from your second code sample. Tibebes's code is about your first code snippet.